# how i can use vuejs component in laravel blade?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, components, render

the idea is to use vue component inside file blade but i got this error

```
Failed to mount component: template or render function not defined.
```

this my importation in app.js

```
Vue.component('Notification' ,require('./components/Notification.vue'));
```

this my component code

```
<template>
     <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
          <i class="fas fa-bell"></i> <span class="badge badge-light">{{unreads.length}}</span>
          <span class="badge badge-warning navbar-badge"></span>
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-lg dropdown-menu-right">
  <notification-item> </notification-item>


        </div>
      </li>

</template>

<script>
    export default {
      props :['unreads','userid'],
        mounted() {
           Echo.private('App.User.'+ this.userid)
    .notification((notification) => {
        console.log(notification);
    });
        }
    }
</script>
```

and finally this my code in home.blade.php

```
<Notification  :userid="{{auth()->id()}}" :unreads="{{auth()->user()->unreadNotifications}}"> </Notification>
```

someone help me please

Comment: You must compile vuejs codes to javascript via webpack etc.

Comment: thank's . i forget to put default in app.js
```
Vue.component('Notification' ,require('./components/Notification.vue'));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Compile vuejs files via `npm run dev` and make sure that you use the correct binding for `userid` and include app.js into scripts.